# Add UITextField to UIToolbar

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitextfield, uitoolbar

I tried this to add UITextField to a UIToolbar but got a run-time error with reason as: [UITextField view]: unrecognized selector sent to instance ...

```
[toolbar setItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:textField, nil]];
```

toolbar is an instance of UIToolbar and textField is an instance of UITextField.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

The `items` of a `UIToolbar` have to be of type `UIBarButtonItem`. Use `initWithCustomView:` to create a toolbar item that contains your text field.

```
UIBarButtonItem *textFieldItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:textField];
toolbar.items = @[textFieldItem];
```

Answer (score 2):

omz's answer above still answered my question in 2017 but here is **an update to iOS 10 and Swift 3**. I am going to create a `UIToolbar`, which has a `UITextField` and `.flexibleSpace` on its left and right sides to center the text field within the toolbar.

```
let toolbar = UIToolbar()
let flexibleBarButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .flexibleSpace, target: self, action: nil)
let textfield = UITextField()
let textfieldBarButton = UIBarButtonItem.init(customView: textfield)
// UIToolbar expects an array of UIBarButtonItems:
toolbar.items = [flexibleBarButton, textfieldBarButton, flexibleBarButton]
view.addSubview(toolbar)
```

You can of course shorten the above code and add the `UIToolbar`'s frame etc. but the above should be a more "legible" example of specifically adding a `UITextField` as a `UIBarButtonItem`.

I hope this helps!